# Edit String in Value folder with SharedPreferences in Android

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-sharedpreferences

I want to edit a String into the "Value" folder, maybe using SharedPreferences. But I can't find any way to do this, changing the value of a string for example by calling @string/stringname seems to be impossible. How can I achieve that?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: AFAIK, you still can't change resources at runtime.

Comment: Put some code what you have tried

Answer (score 1):

You cannot change the contents of the resource files during runtime.

> I want to edit a String into the "Value" folder.

The above is not possible. You can possibly use [`SharedPreferences`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) to store that string of yours, as described in the [docs](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html).

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear. When I mentioned "SharedPreferences" I mean retrieving the string that I need from here assigning the value of the string to the string in my "Value" folder :)